# Good way to store tab data

Tags: c#, tabs, storing-data

I am working on a program with a tabbed interface, my problem is that I need a way to store the data in each tab so it will be the same as it was when the program was shut off. I would like to use a database, but Visual C# express 2010 is not the best with databases, I am thinking of using simple text files, but I think there is probably a better way to do it, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have strongly typed entities and are using [Windows Forms Databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx), then you could just serialize the bound entities (e.g. using XmlSerializer) when exiting your app, and then reserialize them when loading the form when the app restarts.

Comment: I think serializing is the way to go with this.

Comment: will this keep the data different for each user on the computer?

Comment: @StevenGlick Serializing the bound data will give you XML. The simplest would be to store the serialized XML in the user's `LocalApplicationData` folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435037/how-should-i-store-per-user-data-in-winforms