# Setting the background image of a form using an external file - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to add an option for my Windows Froms application which will allow the user to change the background of a certain form to a picture from his computer (let's say a .png type of file)...

How do I get the file from the computer and "convert" it to an Image type? Do I need to add it somehow to properties.resources lib? (and if so, how?).

I tried to do this (obviously, it didn't work...):

```
var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
FD.Filter = "png files|*.png";
if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

    System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);
    BackgroundImage = FD.OpenFile();
}
```

Comment: If you want the image to be used when the user closes the app and reopens it, you'll have to find a way to save the image file and the path to it. Check out the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435037/how-should-i-store-per-user-data-in-winforms)

Comment: not what I needed, but helped anyway... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
      BackgroundImage = FD.OpenFile();
```

To this one

```
      BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(FD.FileName);
```

Comment: any way I can add it to the resources?

Comment: here you can find info about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this to draw the loaded image in the form

```
OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
  Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
  Image image = new Bitmap(openDialog.FileName);
  graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

If needed you can add the filter option.