# Preserve data between application executions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application with some textboxes. My user fills the textboxes and runs some methods, when they close the application data is lost (normally).

I want to keep the value of a couple of textboxes and some local variables. It's not worth it to use `database`, and simple `.txt` files are not clean enough, is there any other simple and brief way of storing little volumes of data between application runs?

I'm not sure but have heard some wisps about resource files, are they good for this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435037/how-should-i-store-per-user-data-in-winforms

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simplest way is binding your textboxes to [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx):

- select texbox you want to preserve
- go to Properties > Data > (ApplicationSettings)
- add application settings binding to Text property
- on `FormClosed` event save application settings

Saving settings:

```
private void Form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Next time when user will start your application, settings will be loaded from user-specific file, and textboxes will be filled with same data as it was before user closed an application last time.

Also in application settings you can store local variables, but you will have to add settings for them manually, and manually read that setting on application start:

- open Properties folder under project > Settings.settings
- add settings you want to store (e.g. MyCounter)
- set MyCounter type, scope, and default value (e.g. int, User, 0)
- read setting to your local variable `var x = Settings.Default.MyCounter`
- on form closed save setting `Settings.Default.MyCounter = x` just before calling `Settings.Default.Save()`

Comment: @mahditahsildari yes, this a winform thing `Data` is a category of properties. If you are looking for property name, then you need `(ApplicationSettings)` property

Comment: I finally got your point :) great, that's what I was looking for, I had seen it before but lost the picture at the backyard of my brain.

Comment: Make sure the Scope of the setting is set to User when you want to save to it. When it is set to application you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following options

1. A local Microsoft Access database which can store small footprint.
2. Use a Dictionary, Serialize / Deserialize to filesystem.
3. The Windows registry.

Comment: Sorry but I stated I don't want to use Database, nor FileSystem, and registry is also declined in answer to lexu.

Comment: @mahditahsildari: well, if you exclude database, registry **and** file system - there's not a whole lot of options left ....

Comment: sorry but , if you want to save user settings which can be reloaded later , you need to store it somewhere. Which kind of application is this?

Comment: I mean I want something like web.config in asp.net which is programatically available and I don't need to write I/O code and open/close files. Thanks

Comment: Well , You can use ConfigurationManager class to write into App.Config in case of windows based application also , if you consider the filesystem access , Web.Config is also stored on harddisk , BTW.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, but with most of them, you're going to be putting a file somewhere, whether it's a text file, resources/config or binary.

Using settings is one option:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C

You can also take the serialization route:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/et91as27.aspx

Or you could possibly look into noSQL databases like MongoDB: http://www.mongodb.org/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows (as the tags imply), have you considered the registry?

Comment: Yes I'm on windows and yes I have thought about registry, but due to some reasons I want the data reside near my application (like other files of application)