# Assign values to the variables one time after the operation for the first time

Tags: c#, winforms, variables

If I need To Make Variables that take value by user at the first run and keep this value when the application restarted and be able to change it any time we need that 
How can I do that in C# public Class??

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve data between application executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020086/preserve-data-between-application-executions)

Comment: i want to make an editable connection string and need it to changed from client to other it like making name space to use it for many projects just change the database name and the user name and password outside the source code i need to change it after deploying the application

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the value, even if the application is restarted can be referred to as 'keeping state'. If you want the application variables to keep state, even through a restart, you will have to store them somewhere else (a database perhaps) and have some logic to then read from the database when the app starts.

Your question is quite generic but if you provided code examples you may get a more detailed answer.

Comment: it's not safe in my application to put this data in another Xml or text also database not a logic option for my case

Comment: depending on what you're developing on, if it's a mobile you could use the local storage on the device to hold that data.

Answer (score 1):

1. a Class may not be needed for it will be just another class which is rather not needed to be implemented.
2. Use a form instead (based on your tag, WinForm)

Let this be the form used for this solution

[image: Form Image]

3. Open solution explorer and double click Properties. Upon opening the Application Properties, click Settings on the left side and make a variable as shown on picture below

[image: Application Settings]

4. Set the form to auto close if the boolean settings is set to true and do the other way around if not. Then you must set the btnSubmit to make the bool setting true upon clicking. Let your application concept's code be as follows. (See picture below)

[image: C# Codes]

(IF YOU CAN'T SEE THE CODE IN THE PICTURE DUE TO RECEIVING CAN'T HANDLE REQUEST FROM IMGUR, the following codes are what the last picture contains)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.launchedFirstTime == true)
            {
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.firstTimeString = txtFirstTimeString.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.launchedFirstTime = true;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
HERE IS THE DEBUGGING OF THE APPLICATION. IT DOES SET VALUES
(See firstTimeString and launchedFirstTime in the LOCALS, found at the lower left of the picture)

[image: Application Settings]

Comment: i tried it but the variable didn't keep the value and the Launch First time value still false what's happened

Comment: i want to make an editable connection string and need it to changed from client to other it like making name space to use it for many projects just change the database name and the user name and password outside the source code i need to change it after deploying the application

Comment: Try rephrasing so that i can get what you would like to happen.

Comment: It does work, it's just that every time you run it on debug, its acts as if you have nothing changed. In other words, every debugs is same as situations when you open the app for the first time. But it works, I'll put an image showing you that the values has been set

Answer (score 0):

you can use xml or txt files to write these values and amend when you need. its just a work around.

Thanks