# Load WinForm with previous ComboBox Value

Tags: c#

I have three ComboBoxs get there value from folder and subfolder. when I close the WinForm
and run it again I have to set ComboBoxs value again..
What I need to do is Save the previous selection of ComboBoxs

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(rootDirectory))
        {
            comboBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
            comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged;
            comboBox1.Enter += comboBox1_Enter;                
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot find folder!!! ");
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var parentDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        comboBox2.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(parentDir).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        var parentDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        comboBox3.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(parentDir).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
   }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parentDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString(), comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());
     }
```

Comment: So save them...

Comment: so, where do you encounter a problem

Comment: when I close the WinForm and Open again I want to Save the Last ComboBoxs Value

Comment: Create a Database (MySQL for example), or a file that is written to disc (such as .csv or .ini or .txt). Store the combo box values in these, then when the application is next initialised, read these files and act according within the C# Program...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - select the combobox

2 - go to Properties > Data > (ApplicationSettings)

3 - add application settings binding to Text property

4 - on FormClosed event save application settings

Saving settings:

```
private void Form_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Credits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020086/preserve-data-between-application-executions)!

Answer (score 0):

First this fiction is incorrect for listing directories, sub directories and files. Bad idea to use dropdown(s).

Use "TreeView" component in win form.

Example : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/display-sub-directories-and-files-in-treeview/

So, you can save/set only the selected value in treeview.

Note : You can also review the recursive functions.

Comment: This does not take into account the fact @Mohamed Ahmed will be closing the application itself. His question is to load the previous values, not improve his functionality.

Comment: thnx @Kemal Koyuncu for your replay. and yes as Hex mention I need to load the previous values