# C# Windows Form, How Can I Keep the picture box changes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I don't know if I wrote the question wrong but here is the problem. I made a winform application with c# and put a picture box for user's profile picture and user can choose personal image.

```
private void changePP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.png)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp; *.png";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {               
        profilePic.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
    }
}
```

But, I don't know how to program keep the picture box changes. I want user to choose own picture and save it. After re-run user should see the choosen picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preserve data between application executions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020086/preserve-data-between-application-executions) Although, there are easily dozens of approaches you can take.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my solution. I have same issues still.

Comment: Look for data persistence, not anything to do with the picturebox etc..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file won't be moved, you can create a settings file saved to disk which includes the location of the file to load. This settings file can be saved in the same location every time, so the program knows to look there for the file.

The steps would be as follows:

1. Create a new class to store the file path of the user's image. This class may expand to include other settings, so you may want to call it something like `UserSettings`
2. When the user selects a file, assign the `open.FileName` to a property on the `UserSettings`
3. Convert the `UserSettings` to text, using something like [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
4. Save the text to disk.
5. When the application loads, see if the settings file exists. If so, load it.
6. Convert the loaded text to a UserSettings object (again using something like Json.net)
7. If the property for the file name is not null, assign that to the picture box.